# How to run Cheese twice, simultaneously

Tags: video, webcam, cheese

I need to show video from two webcams side by side, simultaneously. Roughly like below:
[image: Webcam view]

except I only need two of them. Cheese allows me to choose which webcam I want to display, but when it's running, rerunning Cheese just refocuses the same window, instead of starting a new one. If only I could have two independent windows with Cheese at once, I would pick a different webcam on each and put them side by side.

My question is: can I somehow fool Cheese into thinking it's not already running and starting a new window? Otherwise, can you suggest a similar program which would achieve the same goal?

Comment: Read `man cheese`, with extra attention to the `--device=DEVICE` parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's relevant. I know how to set the device, but I don't know how to run a second instance of Cheese with different `--device` parameter. I tried to make this clear in my question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, from your question and remarks, that you're a GUI-only user. As I'm a mostly command-line user, I'm used to a different way of addressing problems, but here goes.

In your GUI environment, `cheese` is started through a file called `cheese.desktop`, probably located in `$HOME/.config/cairo-dock/current_theme/launchers/cheese.desktop` (or, left as Exercise for the Student, somewhere in the `$HOME/.config/...` directory tree), or you can find the original in `/usr/share/applications/cheese.desktop`. The format of the `desktop` file is described in [the Desktop File Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html)

First, create a temporary working directory, and make TWO copies of your `cheese.desktop` file. Call them `camera1.desktop` and `camera2.desktop`, or anything you want.

Edit `camera1.desktop` and `camera2.desktop`. In each file, change the

```
Exec=cheese
```

and

```
Name=cheese
```

lines to

```
Exec=cheese --device=/dev/camera1
Name=camera1
```

or

```
Exec=cheese --device=/dev/camera2
name=camera2
```

Change ONLY the `Exec=cheese` line and the `Name=cheese` lines.

When you are happy with your changes, copy them back to `$HOME/.config/cairo-dock/current_theme/launchers/` , keeping the `camera1.desktop` and `camera2.desktop` names.

Click on `camera1` to start `cheese --device=/dev/camera1` and `camera2` to start `cheese --device=/dev/camera1`.

Note: I haven't actually tried this.

Comment: Thank you, but you got me wrong. I am a cmd user as well. My goal is not to create two buttons, which start cheese with either device preset. I want to *simulatenously* run two windows of the same app, but different devices. With your solution, I click `camera1` and see video from camera 1, then click `camera2` and it switches to displaying camera 2, instead of (intended behavior) starting a new, simultaneous window with camera 2.

Cheese performs a check (visible in its source) if the app is already running and returns the old window. I want to fool it somehow to always create a new one.

Comment: Since I've only found out about this check after posting this question, it is now more or less "how can I change Cheese's PID/whatever it uses to identify itself, so that it runs twice?". If that's impossible, I will close this question, since what I am asking for is disabled directly in the app's source.